Regularity for computing the first variation
I am having a trouble understanding the regularity needed to compute the first variation for the Euler-Lagrange equation for the functional
$$F(u) = \int f(u) dx$$
Suppose $u:U \to \mathbb{R}$ for bounded $U$. Consider the variation $u_{\tau} = u + \tau \phi$ for some test function $\phi \in C^\infty_0(U)$. Then the first variation
$$\dfrac{d}{d\tau}|_{\tau=0}  F(u_{\tau}) dx = \int f'(u) \dfrac{\partial u_{\tau}}{\partial \tau}|_{\tau=0}$$
Now
$$\dfrac{\partial u_{\tau}}{\partial \tau}|_{\tau=0} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial \tau}|_{\tau=0} \left( u + \tau \phi \right)= \phi$$
My question is what kind of regularity of $u$ is needed for the above calculation to be valid. In particular, assuming that $f$ is $C^1$ and its derivative exists and is bounded, I don't see that there is a need for $u$ to be say $C^1$ or even $C$? Right? How about integrability?
Thanks

Your definition of $F$ isn't well defined. What is the domain of $f$?

I assume it will depend on the answer to my question, that is the regularity needed for u.

You don’t need any “real” regularity on $u$; just assume Lebesgue measurability. Besides that, you essentially need hypotheses on $f$ and $f’$ (in relation to $u$ and $\partial u_{\tau}/\partial \tau$) so that you have enough integrability so that all integrals make sense and that you can push the derivative through the integral.
